# phone sms xml to boxed conversation-like in latex

Tags: tcolorbox, typography, xml

here is a piece of an xml file generated by and android app to backup sms's.

```
<sms protocol="0" address="+1234567890" date="1602132754403" type="1" subject="null" body="Hi, this is first input. ok? " toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+998877665544" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1602132750000" sub_id="1" readable_date="8 oct. 2020 10:22:34" contact_name="yaya" />
```

I'd like from this file, untouched, to get a boxed conversation with one member's inputs on the left and the other on the right. Using tcolorbox I'd like the title containing the value of "address" i.e the phone number of the sender. Inside the box all technical details both at the beginning and the end of each line in the source file must be put at the top with a tiny font and the bottom must be the chat content with normal font. I don't know if it is possible to also have human readable date format.

**Update**

here is a longer xml file as example:

```
<!--File Created By SMS Backup & Restore v10.08.006 on 12/11/2020 18:37:07-->
<!--

To view this file in a more readable format, visit https://synctech.com.au/view-backup/

-->
<smses count="18" backup_set="10d36e93-2204-ba47-c5b3-cef114e63e22" backup_date="1605186427168" type="full">
  <sms protocol="0" address="+112233344455" date="1581427096346" type="1" subject="null" body="Tomorrow positively" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+1627384950" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1581427095000" sub_id="1" readable_date="11 feb. 2020 18:48:16" contact_name="best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+22333 44455" date="1582198718331" type="2" subject="null" body="hello friend, let me know if you're available this weekend..." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" sub_id="1" readable_date="20 feb. 2020 17:08:38" contact_name="best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+112233344455" date="1582199748809" type="1" subject="null" body="Yes you can please come this weekend" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+1627384950" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1582199734000" sub_id="1" readable_date="20 feb. 2020 17:25:48" contact_name="best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+22333 44455" date="1582347025313" type="2" subject="null" body="sunday around 3 pm?" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="0" locked="0" date_sent="1582347033917" sub_id="1" readable_date="22 feb. 2020 10:20:25" contact_name="best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="BT-CTOPUP" date="1585539138933" type="1" subject="null" body="Recharge with $4.85 by 1928374656 on 30/03/2020@08:52:59 AM,GST $7.98 given in main balance,valid till 27/06/20, CB $19.70 Ref.8475601927" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+578493098475" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1585538753000" sub_id="1" readable_date="30 mars 2020 09:02:18" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="BT-CTOPUP" date="1585884332885" type="1" subject="null" body="Recharge with $16 by 45637284 on 03/04/2020@08:52:05 AM,GST $2.44 given in main balance,valid till 27/06/20, CB $19 Ref.625378901" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+578493098475" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1585884336000" sub_id="1" readable_date="3 apr. 2020 08:55:32" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+162738495078" date="1591018139214" type="1" subject="null" body="Hi there, are you ready? " toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+17283940567" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1591018163000" sub_id="1" readable_date="1 june 2020 18:58:59" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="27384 95078" date="1591019084514" type="2" subject="null" body="yes" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="68" locked="0" date_sent="1591106098069" sub_id="1" readable_date="1 june 2020 19:14:44" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="BT-CTOPUP" date="1593410081824" type="1" subject="null" body="Recharge with $6 by 45637284 on 29/06/2020@11:25:21 AM,GST $1.59 given in main balance,valid till 09/11/20, CB $13.5 Ref.4430684" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+578493098475" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1593410112000" sub_id="1" readable_date="29 june 2020 11:24:41" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="27384 95078" date="1593648493160" type="2" subject="null" body="Hot summer is here." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="0" locked="0" date_sent="1593648500171" sub_id="1" readable_date="2 jul. 2020 05:38:13" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+162738495078" date="1593656855536" type="1" subject="null" body="OK will come today" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+17283940567" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1593654668000" sub_id="1" readable_date="2 jul. 2020 07:57:35" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+162738495078" date="1594438358421" type="1" subject="null" body="hi 30 coins for you" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+17283940567" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1594438416000" sub_id="1" readable_date="11 jul. 2020 09:02:38" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+162738495078" date="1594654966188" type="1" subject="null" body="Can you give half to jerry? " toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+17283940567" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1594655018000" sub_id="1" readable_date="13 jul. 2020 21:12:46" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="27384 95078" date="1598325648534" type="2" subject="null" body="hi, long time we last met!" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="0" locked="0" date_sent="1598325653623" sub_id="1" readable_date="25 aug. 2020 08:50:48" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+162738495078" date="1598328721739" type="1" subject="null" body="Indeed, let's meet" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+17283940567" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1598328711000" sub_id="1" readable_date="25 aug. 2020 09:42:01" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="27384 95078" date="1598333198381" type="2" subject="null" body="I'll be out and i'll be back in 2 hrs max." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="0" locked="0" date_sent="1598333206580" sub_id="1" readable_date="25 aug. 2020 10:56:38" contact_name="another best friend" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="+162738495078" date="1598333470558" type="1" subject="null" body="I'm not coming now" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+17283940567" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1598333469000" sub_id="1" readable_date="25 aug. 2020 11:01:10" contact_name="another best friend" />
</smses>
```

In the output i'd like to have only entries dated from 1^st june from "another best friend", which is also type='1' and all those of type='2' from that same date. So all entries from 'best friend' and 'Unknown' should not appear for the case of this example.

**Update 2**

I've been able to implement a function to translate the unix timestamps to readable format.

in the file sms.sty provided in of the answers i added in the luacode part the following:

```
  function epoch (format,time)
  if format == 1 then
    fmt = "%c"
-- below division is for the case time is given in ms instead of sec. And
-- 'time' must be an integer, thus the use of math.floor()
    time = math.floor( time / 1000 )

  elseif format == 2 then
    fmt = "%A"
  elseif format == 3 then
    fmt = "%B"
  elseif format == 4 then
    fmt = "%X"
  else
    fmt = "%x"
  end
  tex.sprint(os.date(fmt, time))
  end
```

then in the smslib.lua the function epoch is used in the double square bracketed parts as :
`\epoch{1}{@{'date_sent'}}`

It works nicely but AFAIK the function epoch, which i found somewhere around, should be improved.

**Update 3**

here is the solution for my request.
smslib.lua

```
-- instead of :
--transform.add_action("sms[type='2']", me_template)
--transform.add_action("sms[type='1']", other_template)

-- do this :
local proc_me = transform.simple_content(me_template)
local proc_other = transform.simple_content(other_template)

local cutoff_date = 1000 * os.time{ year = 2020, month = 10, day = 7 }

transform.add_custom_action("sms[type='2'][address='98407 47754']", 
function(e) if tonumber(e:get_attribute("date")) >= cutoff_date then 
  return proc_me(e) end end )

transform.add_custom_action("sms[type='1'][address='+919840747754']", 
function(e) if tonumber(e:get_attribute("date")) >= cutoff_date then 
  return proc_other(e) end end )
```

**update 4**
Here is the graphical output of the final code with the first tcolorbox created with the tcb environment senderbox from sms.sty in the solution given by michal.h21, called from the file sample.tex. The title and content are hand written there in sample.tex. The second box is created by senderbox called from smslib.lua with other_template =[[\bein{senderbox}[...]{...}@{body}\end{senderbox}]]. Either with the content read from the sms.xml file or manually written in place of @{body} the result is the same. I added a vertical line to highlight the indentations that appear in this case for the content of the box.
[image]

Comment: since you are asking for a conversation layout it would be better to show a bigger test input that had two messages from each person otherwise hard to guess how you ar supposed to pull out the data (are the sms elements all siblings or do you need to traverse a tree or ...)

Comment: yes they're all siblings.

Comment: still easier to test if you provide an example

Comment: It seems doable via `luaxml` + LuaLaTeX (not sure about other engines...). As @DavidCarlisle says, it's easier to play with an example.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio luaxml or cross engine the excellent (!!?) xmltex system could be used.

Comment: I am already working on `luaxml` solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

** Edit **

OP had lot of additional requests, here is the updated code.

The additional functionality filters the XML DOM object before it is transformed to LaTeX code. In particular, it filters messages by date or sender. The updates Lua library `smslib.lua` now looks like this:

```lua
kpse.set_program_name "luatex"
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"

local transform = require "luaxml-transform"

-- module
local M = {}

-- templates for SMS print
-- template for user
local me_template = [[
\begin{mebox}[]{Me}
{\tiny subject:@{subject}, read: @{read}}\\@{readable_date}\tcblower{}@{body}
\end{mebox}
]]

-- template for the person who messages
local other_template = [[
\begin{senderbox}[]{@{contact_name} $\langle$@{address}$\rangle$}
{\tiny subject:@{subject}, read: @{read}}\\@{readable_date}\tcblower{}@{body}
\end{senderbox}

]]

transform.add_action("sms[type='2']", me_template)
transform.add_action("sms[type='1']", other_template)

M.load_xml = function(filename)
  local f, message = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not f then 
    print("XML file error: ", message)
    return nil, message
  end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  content = content:gsub("\r", "")
  local dom = domobject.parse(content)
  return dom
end

local function date_to_sms_time(date)
  local year, month, day = date:match("(%d+)%-(%d+)%-(%d+)")
  if not year then return nil, "Cannot parse date" end
  -- SMS XML dates are multiplied by 1000.
  local base_time = os.time({year = tonumber(year), month = tonumber(month), day = tonumber(day)})
  return  1000 * base_time -- - 24 * 3600
end

-- process all records and execute test function
M.filter = function(dom, fn)
  for _, rec in ipairs(dom:query_selector("sms")) do
    -- if test function returns true, the record will be removed
    local status = fn(rec)
    if status then 
      rec:remove_node()
    end
  end
end

M.from_date = function(dom, date)
  local startday, msg = date_to_sms_time(date)
  if not startday then return nil, msg end
  M.filter(dom, function(rec)
    local date = tonumber(rec:get_attribute("date_sent") or "")
    return date < startday 
  end)
end

-- set international phone number prefix
M.set_number_prefix = function(prefix)
  M.prefix = prefix
end

-- compare two phone numbers. we must normalize them
-- by removing spaces and adding international prefix
-- if it is missing in one of numbers
M.match_numbers = function(first, second)
  local prefix = M.prefix or ""
  local normalize = function(number)
    if not number:match("^%+") then number = prefix .. number end
    return number:gsub("%s", "")
  end
  return normalize(first) == normalize(second)
end

  


M.filter_sender = function(dom, sender)
  if sender == "" then return nil, "empty sender" end
  M.filter(dom, function(rec)
    local typ = rec:get_attribute("type") 
    local address = rec:get_attribute("address")
    -- remove all sms that are not part of the conversation with this number
    return M.match_numbers(address, sender) ~= true
  end)
end




M.process_xml = function(dom)
  local converted = transform.process_dom(dom)
  tex.print(converted)
end

-- M.process_xml("messages.xml")

return M
```

The filter function loops over all SMS messages and tests them using function that it takes as a parameter. If the function tests positively, it removes the message. There are two filtering functions, one removes messages older than a date, second removes incoming texts that don't come from a number.

We need to update the `sms.sty` package as well, because we want to be able to pass the date and sender number to filters:

```
\ProvidesPackage{sms}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
smslib = require "smslib"
\end{luacode*}

% settings for the boxes
% modify the values to your liking
\newtcolorbox{mebox}[2][]{%
colback=blue!10!white,colframe=red!70!black,
halign title=right,
title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1}

\newtcolorbox{senderbox}[2][]{%
colback=blue!10!white,colframe=blue!70!black,
title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1}

\def\printsms@fromdate{}
\def\printsms@sender{}
% international phone number prefix. this is the default value
% you can change it using the prefix key in \printsms
\def\printsms@prefix{+16}
% some keyval attributes
\define@key{printsms}{fromdate}[]{\def\printsms@fromdate{#1}}
\define@key{printsms}{sender}[]{\def\printsms@sender{#1}}
\define@key{printsms}{prefix}[+16]{\def\printsms@prefix{#1}}


% Command that will process the SMS XML file and print the boxes
\newcommand\printsms[2][]{%
 \bgroup%
 \setkeys{printsms}{#1}%
 \directlua{%
  local dom = smslib.load_xml("#2")
  smslib.set_number_prefix("\printsms@prefix")
  smslib.from_date(dom,"\printsms@fromdate")
  smslib.filter_sender(dom, "\printsms@sender")
  smslib.process_xml(dom)
  }%
  \egroup%
}

\endinput
```

The `\printsms` now takes some keyval options, which can be used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sms}
\begin{document}
\printsms[fromdate=2020-06-01,sender=+162738495078]{newmessages.xml}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

**Original answer:**

This is quite easy to do using LuaXML, especailly using the new `luaxml-transform` library. This library can transform XML files using CSS selectors and simple templates to any output format.

I would provide a special LuaLaTeX package to handle this task. It consists of two files, `sms.sty` package, which contains TeX declarations, and `smslib.lua`, which do the transformation.

Here is the `sms.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{sms}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
smslib = require "smslib"
\end{luacode*}

% settings for the boxes
% modify the values to your liking
\newtcolorbox{mebox}[2][]{%
colback=blue!10!white,colframe=red!70!black,
halign title=right,
title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1}

\newtcolorbox{senderbox}[2][]{%
colback=blue!10!white,colframe=blue!70!black,
title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1}

% Command that will process the SMS XML file and print the boxes
\newcommand\printsms[1]{%
 \directlua{%
  smslib.process_xml("#1")
  }%
}

\endinput
```

It loads `tcolorbox` and defines two new box types, `mebox` will be used to print messages from you, `senderbox` will be used for incoming messages. You can change colors and other formatting details here.

The `\printsms` command takes name of the XML file and passes it to the `smslib.lua` library, which can look like this:

```lua
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"

-- module
local M = {}

-- templates for SMS print
-- template for user
local me_template = [[
\begin{mebox}[]{Me}
{\tiny subject:@{subject}, read: @{read} }\\
@{readable_date}
\tcblower
@{body}
\end{mebox}
]]

-- template for the person who messages
local other_template = [[
\begin{senderbox}[]{@{contact_name} $\langle$@{address}$\rangle$}
{\tiny subject:@{subject}, read: @{read} }\\
@{readable_date}
\tcblower
@{body}
\end{senderbox}

]]

transform.add_action("sms[type='2']", me_template)
transform.add_action("sms[type='1']", other_template)


M.process_xml = function(filename)
  local f, message = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not f then 
    print("XML file error: ", message)
    return nil, message
  end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  content = content:gsub("\r", "")
  local dom = domobject.parse(content)
  local converted = transform.process_dom(dom)
  tex.print(converted)
end



return M
```

The important part is this:

```lua
local me_template = [[
\begin{mebox}[]{Me}
{\tiny subject:@{subject}, read: @{read} }\\
@{readable_date}
\tcblower
@{body}
\end{mebox}
]]

-- template for the person who messages
local other_template = [[
\begin{senderbox}[]{@{contact_name} $\langle$@{address}$\rangle$}
{\tiny subject:@{subject}, read: @{read} }\\
@{readable_date}
\tcblower
@{body}
\end{senderbox}

]]

transform.add_action("sms[type='2']", me_template)
transform.add_action("sms[type='1']", other_template)
```

The transform library process the XML file and tests all elements for actions that are declared using `add_action`. The first argument is a CSS selector that is used for matching, second is the transformation template.

Two actions are declared here, both of them for the `<sms>` element. I've found that the exported SMS XML differentiates between out-coming and incoming messages using the `type` attribute. Incoming have value `1` and out-coming have value `2`.  `[type='1']` tests for these attributes and the correct template is called depending of it's value.

The `me_template` and `other_template` variables contains string templates that will print the messages. `@{attribute_name}` strings can be used to print values of the `<sms>` element attributes. So for example `@{body}` outputs the message text. You can edit the templates to include more attributes that you want.

I've found a full sample of the XML file. I've added also your sample to this file, `messages.xml`:

```xml
<smses count="3">
<sms protocol="0" address="+1234567890" date="1602132754403" type="1" subject="null" body="Hi, this is first input. ok? " toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+998877665544" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1602132750000" sub_id="1" readable_date="8 oct. 2020 10:22:34" contact_name="yaya" />
<sms protocol="0" address="332" date="1285799668193" type="2" subject="null" body="Sample Message Sent from the phone" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" readable_date="Sep 30, 2010 8:34:28 AM" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
<sms protocol="0" address="4433221123" date="1289643415810" type="1" subject="null" body="Sample Message received by the phone" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="0" status="-1" locked="0" readable_date="Nov 13, 2010 9:16:55 PM" contact_name="(Unknown)" />
</smses>
```

Here is a sample TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sms}
\begin{document}
\printsms{messages.xml}
\end{document}
```

And this is the resulting PDF:

[image]

Comment: i'm still trying it. I only tried it quickly but it didn't run. lualatex must be used here right? for the ' require "smslib" ' i put the the file smslib.lua in the base directory of the whole project. Or should i install it somewhere like ~/texmf?

Comment: @user1850133 yes,  `lualatex` is necessary for the compilation. It also needs relatively recent version of LuaXML, from January. So you may need to update your TeX distribution, or download it from CTAN and install it to your TEXMF. But TeX Live update will be probably easier.

Comment: i did a manual install of your LuaXML in ~/texmf/script/lua and it worked. i'll see more in deep your code a bit later.

Comment: Actually in my xml file, end of lines are of windows style, i.e. crlf, in vim the character '^M' is printed. It seems the problem comes from luaxml-domobject. Is there any option to be used here?

Comment: @user1850133 does it cause some issues, for example, is the `^M` character printed in the PDF?

Comment: i forgot to mention that there is a problem and what it is. Actually the pdf file contains only the sms entries up to the ^M character (0x0d) from my xml file.

Comment: @user1850133 ah I see. I think this is an issue in LuaTeX's `tex.print`, because Lua itself doesn't have this problem. I've updates `smslib.lua` with function that removes the `^M` character from the XML file before processing. It seems to fix this issue.

Comment: yes, it works. Actually this solution is exactly what i needed.

Comment: for the lines transform.add_action("sms[type='x]", xxxx) is there a way to select the lines on the basis of several fields? In the xml file all entries with type='2' are the sender, which is always the same physical device. Those with type='1' could be anyone but the sender. I'd like to select entries on the basis of 'type' && 'address'. Also selecting on the basis of a time period like all sms's received between 1st oct. and 30th oct. Another point, could the 'date*' fields be converted into a human readable format.

Comment: @user1850133 something like `ransform.add_action("sms[type='1'][address='xxxx']",xxx)` should work, I think. but better solution would be to use LuaXML's functions to modify the XML file before the templates are applied. I have COVID 19 and I am bit tired, so I cannot provide an example right now, but I can update my answer later. Could you update your question with a XML file and details about what you need?

Comment: i just tried your suggestion, it seems the operator between [type='1'] and [address='xxxx'] would rather be OR. I'll update my question tomorrow.

Comment: are you still on? did you check my updates?

Comment: @user1850133 I am still not feeling well, I cannot work on computer for too long, unfortunately :(

Comment: maybe you're better now. I updated my post and i'm showing the graphical output to show that boxes created by the call in smslib.lua have their content paragraphs indented. I tried things such as \setlength{\parindent}{0em} or \noindent but they don't change anything.

Comment: @user1850133 sorry for the long delay. I am finally fine and updated my answer.

Comment: i tried your new solution. Why building the code takes a lot more time now? it's nearly 5 to 10 times slower now. Also previously as i shown in my "update 3" i was using "sms[type='2'][address='dest. address']" to select sms's from sender on the basis of destination address too. With your new solution all sender's sms's from "fromdate" date disregarding to which address they are sent, are printed in the output document.

Comment: @user1850133 I didn't notice any slowdown, but it is true that I don't remember, how fast was the compilation before.

Comment: i checked again it's because of another change i did in the meantime that it was slowing down.

Comment: in my comment by "sender's sms's" i mean sms with type="2"

Comment: @user1850133 ah, I see. I've updated both `smslib.lua` and `sms.sty`. The now filter also sender's sms. There was a problem that the phone numbers in received and sent sms were different in the xml file. I've added some phone number normalizing code, you may need to change the phone number prefix to match your country code.